# convert normal array in nested array with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a hierarchical database table like below

```
ID  Name    Subcategory ParentID
1   ABC                     0
2   DEF         QFE         0
3   QFE         XYZ         2
4   XYZ         MNJ         3
```

From Thant I have got PHP array like below

```
$array_name =  array(
                array('ID' => '1', 'Name' => 'ABC', 'Subcategory' => '', 'ParentID' => '0'),
                array('ID' => '2', 'Name' => 'DEF', 'Subcategory' => 'QFE', 'ParentID' => '0'),
                array('ID' => '3', 'Name' => 'QFE', 'Subcategory' => 'XYZ', 'ParentID' => '2'),
                array('ID' => '4', 'Name' => 'XYZ', 'Subcategory' => 'MNJ', 'ParentID' => '3')
            );
```

but I want array like below

```
$array_name = array(
                array('ID' => '1', 'Name' => 'ABC', 'Subcategory' => '', 'ParentID' => '0'),
                array('ID' => '2', 'Name' => 'DEF', 'Subcategory' => array('ID' => '3', 'Name' => 'QFE', 'Subcategory' => array('ID' => '4', 'Name' => 'XYZ', 'Subcategory' => 'MNJ', 'ParentID' => '3'), 'ParentID' => '2'), 'ParentID' => '0'),                   
                );
```

I want a function which checks is that row have some  Subcategory or not and if a row has Subcategory then get that subcategory row as an array and make one array with all category and Subcategory

for that, I have tried to make a function which is given below

```
function find_subcategory($ID,$con){
$table_name ="SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `parent_id` = '$ID'";
$table_name_result = mysqli_query($con,$table_name);
$category_array = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($table_name_result)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_name_result)) {
        $Subcategory= $row['Subcategory'];
        $ID = $row['ID'];
        if ($Subcategory== '') {
            $find_subcategory = find_subcategory($ID,$con);
            $row['Subcategory'] = $find_subcategory;
            $category_array[] = $row;
        }else{
            $category_array[] = $row;
        }

    }
}   
return json_encode(array('tbl_category'=>$category_array));
}
```

but this function is not working to get all the subcategories of one category.

can anybody help me with this

Comment: Where does $row["type"] come from? It's not in your representation of the dataset.

Comment: Is the `ParentID` field an indication of the level of nesting you require for that row?

Comment: I assume he needs to keep looking for possible children for every row, and subrow and subsubrow recursively. I don't think there's a way to know in advance how deep the recursion goes for each row.

Comment: @UrsolSolutions, I think the `ParentID` field is what should control the level of nesting - hence, the degree of recursion. I asked the question so as to be sure that the asker is aware of it.

Comment: @UdoE. yes this is a hierarchical table as like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3887780074b7e6902279cea95bcdb0c and parentid indicates level

Comment: ok. let me help in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create a recursive routine, which executes the SQL for each level, this instead reads all of the categories in and them assembles them into the hierarchy.

Note that it reads them in reverse order so that when it assembles them, each subcategory is always read before the parent (More details in code comments)...

```
$table_name ="SELECT * FROM `category` ORDER BY parent_id DESC, id desc";
$table_name_result = mysqli_query($con,$table_name);
$categories = mysqli_fetch_all($table_name_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$output= [];
foreach ( $categories as $category) {
    // If there is a parent for this item
    if ( !empty ($category['parent_id']) )  {
        // Set basic details
        $output[$category['parent_id']]['Subcategory'][$category['id']] = $category;
        // If there is already some data (subcategories)
        if ( isset($output[$category['id']]) ){
            // Copy subcategories
            $output[$category['parent_id']]['Subcategory'][$category['id']] += 
                            $output[$category['id']];
            // Remove old node
            unset ( $output[$category['id']] );
        }
    }
    else    {
        // Add in category data (allow for existing data to be added
        $output[$category['id']] = $category + ($output[$category['id']]??[]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I worked out something similar. But I believe it needs more recursion.

Comment: @UrsolSolutions, why does it need recursion?

Comment: I see you ordered by parent_id and then went in reverse order. Does this ensure subcategories will also have filled subcategories, and so on?

Comment: @UrsolSolutions, it's done so that any child record is loaded before it's parent record, so that it can roll up the data rather than having to do much else.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Sorry I missed that before ^^

Comment: @NigelRen can you explain else portion little bit I can not understand it properly

Comment: The else part adds any data ( item, name etc.) to the existing item(using `??[]` means if there isn't an existing item, just add a blank array).  This means any Subcategory data is added to rather than overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully implemented and tested a recursive routine to solve this. However, for performance reasons I had to decouple the access to the database from the recursive call.

First, you fetch your query into an array as you already have and then recursively rearrange the elements so that the keys are nested in the proper order.

Pretty much of the explanations I'd like to put here are put as comments in the code.

```php
$array_name =  array(
    array('ID' => '1', 'Name' => 'ABC', 'Subcategory' => '', 'ParentID' => '0'),
    array('ID' => '2', 'Name' => 'DEF', 'Subcategory' => 'QFE', 'ParentID' => '0'),
    array('ID' => '3', 'Name' => 'QFE', 'Subcategory' => 'XYZ', 'ParentID' => '2'),
    array('ID' => '4', 'Name' => 'XYZ', 'Subcategory' => 'MNJ', 'ParentID' => '3'),
    array('ID' => '5', 'Name' => 'XYY', 'Subcategory' => 'MNJ', 'ParentID' => '1')
);

// recreate nested array
function get_nested_array($arr) {
    $new_arr = array(); // new array to collect each top level element with nesting
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        // only top level elements would appear here as they would not be nested
        if($value['ParentID'] == '0') {
            array_push($new_arr, get_nested_item($value, $arr));
        }
    }
    return $new_arr;
}

// recursive function to perform nesting on each element
function get_nested_item($hay, $stack) {
    foreach ($stack as $key => $value) {
        if ($hay['ID'] == $value['ParentID']) {
            $index = get_key($hay, $stack);
            // reduce $stack size by removing the HAY from the STACK
            // recursion terminates when $stack size is 0
            $stack = $index >= 0 ? array_splice($stack, $index) : [];
            // update subcategory of the found nesting
            $hay['Subcategory'] = get_nested_item($value, $stack);
        }
    }
    return $hay;
}

// get the position of $hay in a $stack using the ID
function get_key($hay, $stack) {
    foreach ($stack as $key => $value) {
        if($hay['ID'] == $value['ID']) return $key;
    }
    return -1;
}

// print array so that it understandable
function print_array($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        print_r($value);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

// Test case
// print array before nesting
print_array($array_name);
echo"<br>";

// print array after nesting
$new_array = get_nested_array($array_name);
print_array($new_array);
```